# Concrete5.8 how to make tranlsation of the database values?

Tags: translation, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

In Concrete5.8 how to make translation of the database values? For say i have table types.. and my site is in 2 languages now the values of the types field i need the translation in both language so how is this possible in here? As in old 5.6 version package was available for this which was working fine for db translation but what for new version ?

For example i have bycycle which types are dynamic for example say "sports" which will be diff. for dif. language and types is to be dynamic so i have to manage it with database.. So how can i get diff. translations for it

Can anyone please help me

Comment: Can you clarify why those tables need translating in the first place? Where/how are they shown to the end user? How are they reflected in C5?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. For example my i have bycycle which types are dynamic for example say "sports" which will be diff. for dif. language and types is to be dynamic so i have to manage it with database.. So how can i get diff. translations for it

Comment: Can you point to the package you were using in 5.6?

Comment: I was using this one https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/localizer

Comment: Might be worth asking them whether a 5.8 version is in the works - or asking in the forum whether anyone knows anything. I'm not really clear how/where you are outputting this stuff - in theory, I suppose you could pipe into C5's own localization system and add your own localized terms, although I'm hazy on how that's done there right now. Their forum might get you a better answer